# How to handle PowerShell Secure Strings

Tags: powershell

How do I properly enter and store a secure password? I am needing to Convert it from Secure in order to put in to JSON to get a REST token.

My example is:

> PS C:\Temp> $secpass = Read-Host -assecurestring "Please enter password";
>
> Please enter password: *****
>
> PS C:\Temp> echo $secpass
>
> System.Security.SecureString
>
> PS C:\Temp> $pass =
>   ConvertFrom-SecureString $secpass
>
> PS C:\Temp> echo $pass
>   01000000d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb010000004fe37b5a39a93542a74298c3740cae0b0000000002000000000003660000c00000001000000096aa9947681adf56ce6f9fd2d9ced2140000000004800000a0000000100000006bbff8b1e2115682e9be4c775d8372ee10000000b80a4a99147901275a9080c257712b1914000000010eabc8c134837751dbd2d648dbbca1f7335e9f
>
> PS C:\Temp>

I want to run the ConvertFrom-SecureString and get my simple plain text password back.

EDIT;

I have the following function that obtains a REST Token:

```
function Get-AuthToken {
    Param(
        [string]$server,
        [string]$username,
        [securestring]$password
    )

        $creds = @{
        username = $username
        password = $password
        grant_type = "password"
        };

    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post "$server/api/token" -Body $creds

}
```

To build $creds correctly the password needs to be in plain text.

Furthermore I also have the following to cover the case where password string is not given when the script is run:

```
If(!$Password) {
            [ValidatePattern("\w+")]$password = Read-Host -assecurestring "Please enter password";
            }
```

As per first answer given here [Convert a secure string to plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352141/convert-a-secure-string-to-plain-text) I have tried to add the following before calling the Get-AuthToken function:

```
$BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($Password)
$unsecurePassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
$response = Get-AuthToken -username $User -password $unsecurePassword -server $server
```

If I do a Write-Host $unsecurePassword I can see the correct string however the Get-AuthToken fails authentication.

EDIT 2:

If I change the function to :

```
function Get-AuthToken {
        Param(
            [string]$server,
            [string]$username,
            [string]$password
        )

            $creds = @{
            username = $username
            password = $password
            grant_type = "password"
            };

        Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post "$server/api/token" -Body $creds

    }
```

Which is making the $password parameter a string rather than a secure string then it works however  don't believe this is best practice since Visual Studio Code is complaining.

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/03/26/decrypt-powershell-secure-string-password/

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended for production systems but try this:

```
$secpass = Read-Host -assecurestring "Please enter password"
$credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("UserTest", $secpass, "Domain")
$credentials.Password
```

You cannot do that with ConvertFrom-SecureString

Comment: `I want to run the ConvertFrom-SecureString and get my simple plain text password back.`

Comment: @Shmukko - Not sure I want to do this if it's not suitable for a production system. See my edit above for more detail.