# Passing secure text between two servers with powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a script that export certificate from Server A to PFX, copy it to Server B and import the PFX to the server.
I'm using the following code to encrypt the password from plain text to secure string:

```
$pfxPass = "PassW0rd"
$File = "D:\backup_conf\Password.txt"
[Byte[]] $key = (1..16)
$pfxSecure = $pfxPass | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$pfxSecure | ConvertFrom-SecureString -key $key | Out-File $File
dir Cert:\LocalMachine\my | Where-Object { $_.NotAfter -clike "*2019*"} | % { certutil.exe -f -exportPFX -p $pfxSecure $_.Thumbprint D:\backup_conf\certificates\$($_.Thumbprint).pfx }
```

PFX created and I can see that Password.txt contains the hash string.
The PFX and the Password.txt were copied over to new server and I've used the following code for import:

```
$file = "D:\backup_conf\Password.txt"
[Byte[]] $key = (1..16)
$pfxSecure = Get-Content $File | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key
$certs = (Get-ChildItem -recurse -Path  "D:\backup_conf\certificates" -Include *.pfx)|%{Import-PfxCertificate $_.FullName -Exportable -Password $pfxSecure -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My }
```

This one fails with the error:

*Import-PfxCertificate : The PFX file you are trying to import requires either a different password or membership in an Active 
Directory principal to which it is protected.*

Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: You're using `SecureString` object here: `certutil.exe -f -exportPFX -p $pfxSecure`. Password will be literally `System.Security.SecureString`. For cmd `SecureString` is not something it can process.

Comment: Thanks. I understand, however, I cannot pass plain text to certutil.exe.
I'm forced to convert it to SecureString.
Any idea on how I can do it properly?
Thanks in advance

Comment: From what I know `certutil.exe` will not accept `SecureString` so you'll have to convert it back to plain text before running it ([here an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352141/convert-a-secure-string-to-plain-text)).

Comment: Thanks, I ended up removing the SecureString as suggested from Server A and used certutil to import the pfx without converting to SecureString on Server B.
Worked.

Comment: Glad to hear! I'll convert it to an answer then and if you want, you can [mark this as answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using `SecureString` object here: `certutil.exe -f -exportPFX -p $pfxSecure` it's not properly recognized by `certutil.exe`. Password will be literally

```
System.Security.SecureString
```

For cmd applications `SecureString` is not something it can process so you'll have to convert it to plain text and then pass it to `certutil.exe`.

Example how you can convert `SecureString` to plain text ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352141/convert-a-secure-string-to-plain-text)):

```
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $pfxPass 
$BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($SecurePassword)
$UnsecurePassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
```