# How do you decrypt securestring in powershell

Tags: powershell

```
$Variable = Read-Host "Enter thing" -AsSecureString
```

Will prompt you for input and save it as a secure string to variable. How do I decrypt a secure string variable?

```
PS C:\Users\Todd> $Variable
System.Security.SecureString
```

Comment: I see that this question has already two (good) answers but I think it is actually a duplicate  with at least [Get SecureString as a Plain Text Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54371160/1701026) and [Convert a secure string to plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28353003/1701026)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$password = Read-Host "Enter password" -AsSecureString
$password = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($password)
$password = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringBSTR($password)
echo $password
pause
```

To convert `Read-Host` `SecureString`s to normal strings, you use

```
$NewVaraible = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($ReadVariable)
$NewNewVariable = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringBSTR($NewVariable)
```

Or you could just update the existing variable:

```
$ReadVaraible = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($ReadVariable)
$ReadVariable = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringBSTR($ReadVariable)
```

---

<sup>Thank you @mklement0 for your insightful comments; updated answer accordingly to mklement0's comment</sup>

Comment: I know that use of `PtrToStringAuto()` is very common, but it is conceptually flawed and breaks on Unix-like platforms; use `PtrToStringBSTR()` instead - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60406968/45375). Also - again something that is commonly missing - you should call `[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeBSTR($NewVariable)` afterward, to zero out and free the BSTR.

Answer (score 17):

A **security warning** first:

**Converting a secure string to a regular `[string]` instance defeats the very purpose of using `[securestring]` ([`System.Security.SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Security.SecureString)) to begin with**: you'll end up with a plain-text representation of your sensitive data in your process' memory whose lifetime you cannot control.

Also, note that secure strings are generally [not recommended for use in new code anymore](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md): they offer only limited protection on Windows, and virtually none on Unix-like platforms, where they aren't even encrypted.

---

**PowerShell v7+** now offers `ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText` to convert a secure string to its - unsecured - plain-text representation:

```bash
# PowerShell 7.0 or higher.
$password = Read-Host "Enter password" -AsSecureString
$plainTextPassword = ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText $password
```

In **PowerShell v6-** (including Windows PowerShell), you can use the following:

```bash
$password = Read-Host "Enter password" -AsSecureString
$plainTextPassword = [Net.NetworkCredential]::new('', $password).Password
```

Comment: +1 for new PS 7 implementation, question: If you are using the built in PowerShell encryption, is it really intended to be secure or just secure enough that it satisfies the casual users?

Comment: @NekoMusume No, it isn't secure: any method, whatever it is, that results in a plain-text representation of a secret is by definition not secure. The methods shown in this answer are simply more convenient than the `[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]`-based approach from your own answer; btw, can you please fix your answer based on the suggestions in my comment?

Comment: Ok, one more thing, your comment talks about `[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeBSTR()` but if I run `[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeBSTR($Password)` it has an error ```Cannot convert argument "s", with value: "Test", for "ZeroFreeBSTR" to type "System.IntPtr": "Cannot convert the "Test" value of type
"System.String" to type "System.IntPtr"."``` is this intended?

Comment: @NekoMusume Thanks for updating. You must call `ZeroFreeBSTR()` on whatever the `SecureStringToBSTR` call returned; here's a full example: `$secure = Read-Host -AsSecureString 'Enter password'; $bstr = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secure); $plaintext = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringBSTR($bstr); [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeBSTR($secure)`