# Get Azure Devops Secret Variable as Plain Text using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

is it possible to retrieve an AzDO Library server variable and output to plain text using a Powershell task? I know we can output the variable to a text file but my use case requires PS script but have found no way to achieve it.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352141/convert-a-secure-string-to-plain-text/28353003#28353003) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54370482/get-securestring-as-a-plain-text-parameter/54371160#54371160) and, with some modifications, it is possible to retrieve passwords and Azure keyvault secrets as plain text, but it does not work with an AzDO secret.

I have mostly been trying with a variation of this but the new "non-secret" variable remains asterisked:

```
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $(testStringSecret) -AsPlainText -Force
$ssPtr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($SecurePassword)
try {$secretValueText = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringBSTR($ssPtr)}
finally {[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeBSTR($ssPtr)}
```

Has anybody managed to it, and if so, are you able to provide details on what you did please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before your attempts to change it to plain text, what is the TypeName given If you pipe the variable to `Get-Member`?

Comment: @BoogaRoo When I piped it, it was showing as a regular string, hence my need to convert to secure string at the very beginning.

Comment: If it's coming to you as asterisks and it's a plain string, no amount of converting to secure strings and back can "recover" it. I think you'll have to find a way to get it out of Azure unmasked.

Comment: If you your secret is masked - I mean printed as `******`. That's fine. It is still plain text but it masked the value on streaming it to logs to be sure that it is not revealed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I attempted to improve the readability of @KUTlime's suggestion/hack by changing the output to horizontal. The variable '$secret' in my example should contain the secret retrieved from the keyVault.

```
$secret = "fOoBaR"
Remove-Variable joined -Force -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
for($i = 0; $i -lt $secret.Length; $i++){
    if ($joined) {$joined = $($joined+" "+$($secret[$i]))}
    else {$joined = $($secret[$i])}
}
Write-output "Secret: >$($joined)<"
```

Outputs:

```
Secret: >f O o B a R<
```

The angle brackets are there to reveal potential space characters trailing the 'secret'.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that by the output you mean a pipeline log.

A simple answer is **no, you can't do that.**

ADO has a filter in the log pre-processor to filter out your secrets. Once the secret is saved as a secret, you can't retrieve it as a plain text in UI either.

But...

---

...you can get creative. Something like this:

```
$secret = 'YourSecret'; for($i = 0; $i -lt $secret.Length; $i++){Write-Host "$($secret[$i])"}
```

With text output:

```
Y
o
u
r
S
e
c
r
e
t
```

Replace the variable `$secret` with the secret ID which you want to display as a plain text and you are good to go.