# Using encrypted password to SSH to multiple servers using Plink

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, ssh, password-encryption, plink

My batch file code requires to run some shell commands on multiple servers using SSH. For that I'm using Plink from a `for` loop.

I do not want to enter the password in plain text to the Plink command line using `-pw`. Instead, due to security concerns, I want to use a password encryption for my password and store the password into a separate text file.

I tried using `sshpass`, but that is not supported in batch. As request to run the code will be on multiple servers, so I don't want to generate SSH key pair for each server as it will not be possible for hundreds of servers in the environment.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (path\to\servers.txt) DO (
    plink -v -ssh user@%%a -pw MY_PASSWORD echo %%a ; cat /path/to/config_file
)
pause
```

I expect the batch script to run on all servers using encrypted password. But with current code, the output is displayed using plain password.

Comment: You do not need to generate a new key pair for each server. You can use the same key (as you seem to be using the same password anyway).

Comment: Thanks for the help @MartinPrikryl, but i don't have the rights to make passwordless connections from windows server to all unix boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to achieve this with a plain batch file.

But you can use PowerShell instead with its [`ConvertTo-SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertto-securestring) and [`ConvertFrom-SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertfrom-securestring) cmdlets.

To encrypt a password use:

```bsh
Read-Host -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString
```

Type the password and save the output to a file (`encryptedpassword.txt`).

To use the encrypted password, use:

```bsh
$encrypted = ConvertTo-SecureString(Get-Content ".\encryptedpassword.txt")
$bstr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($encrypted)
$password = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($bstr)

foreach ($hostname in (Get-Content ".\servers.txt"))
{
    .\plink user@$hostname -pw "$password"
}
```

In PowerShell 7, you can simplify the code to:

```bsh
$encrypted = ConvertTo-SecureString(Get-Content ".\encryptedpassword.txt")
$password = ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $encrypted -AsPlainText
# ...
```

---

Based on:

- My article [Protecting credentials used for automation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_protecting_credentials_for_automation)
- And SO question [Convert a secure string to plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28352141/850848)

---

*Though I have to repeat that using a public key authentication would be a way better solution.*

Comment: Thanks @MartinPrikryl !! It worked just fine for me with this approach.