# Pass Stored Creds to bat file

Tags: powershell, credentials

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to take a stored credential in Windows Cred vault and pass it to a bat file that needs the credentials. I found a very old bat file that has a username and password in clear text. These are used to authenticate against a portal and have to be read by the bat in clear text. I have stored credentials on my server that I want to use so I can close this security gap but I am not 100% sure how to pass the password because it has to be in clear text. Here is what I have:

```
$creds = Get-StoredCredential -Target "Username"
$password = $creds.Password
$username = $creds.UserName
Start-Process cmd.exe "/c C:\trigger.bat `"argument1`" $username $password `"Argument2`" Argument3" -NoNewWindow -Verbose
```

When I enter the password in clear text in my line it works. If I use $password it throws an auth error. I assume that this is because the $password is a stored PSObject and isn't getting passed to cmd "correctly". Is there a way around this?

PS: Get-StoredCredential is from the CredentialManager module.

Comment: Is it not working? (Don't forget to ask your question.)

Comment: Thank you. I added some details and my question.

Comment: Do `$username` and `$password` contain the values you expect them to?  I tested this module ([PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/CredentialManager/), [GitHub](https://github.com/davotronic5000/PowerShell_Credential_Manager)) and a password I saved for accessing a standalone SMB server is returned with an empty `Password` property, though I couldn't get it to produce any (non-warning) results without passing `-AsCredentialObject`.

Comment: Yes, when called I get the standard hash table with User name populated correctly and the password is "System.Security.SecureString"

Comment: To add a little more detail so it becomes more convoluted. The bat file is a vendor provided file that then takes the parameter of the bat file passes it into a compiled Jar file where it authenticates against my AD structure through SSO enabled on the application. If I type the credentials in clear text this all works, for obvious reasons this is not ideal.

Comment: I had written an answer based on [a different `Get-StoredCredential`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/f5-deploy/1.0.50/Content/public%5CGet-StoredCredential.ps1), but perhaps it's still applicable.  When I invoke `Get-StoredCredential` from the `CredentialManager` module the result object's `Password` property I believe was of type `String`, but maybe that's just because I used `-AsCredentialObject`.  I will undelete and edit my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$creds` contains a `PSCredential` object, then you should be able to replace this:

```
$password = $creds.Password
```

with this:

```
$password = $creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you. Didn't even see that method.

Answer (score 2):

[`Get-StoredCredential`](https://github.com/davotronic5000/PowerShell_Credential_Manager), when called without `-AsCredentialObject`, [yields `PSCredential` instances](https://github.com/davotronic5000/PowerShell_Credential_Manager/blob/5ff3fbf137d027c31ada0b82055f3ca341f28efd/PSCredentialManager.Cmdlet/Cmdlets.cs#L95).
The [`PSCredential.Password` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscredential.password) you are accessing is not a `String` but a [`SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring), so you cannot retrieve the plain text password like you are attempting.

Based on [Convert a secure string to plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28352141/150605) you can use the [`PSCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscredential) to [get a `NetworkCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscredential.getnetworkcredential) and then use its [`Password`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.networkcredential.password) property...

```bsh
$password = $creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

In any case, when you get an authentication error using `$username` and `$password` you should ensure those variables contain the values you expect them to.