# PowerShell error when converting a SecureString back to plain text

Tags: powershell

How do I convert a ***SecureString*** back to plain text?

From **Example 4** of the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertfrom-securestring?view=powershell-7).

```
$secureString = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'Example' -AsPlainText
$secureString # 'System.Security.SecureString'
ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $secureString -AsPlainText # 'Example'
```

But when I try the following:

```
>> $secureString = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'Example' -AsPlainText -Force
>> $secureString # 'System.Security.SecureString'
>> ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $secureString -AsPlainText # 'Example'
```

I get this error:

```
ConvertFrom-SecureString : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'AsPlainText'.
At line:3 char:54
+ ... ertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $secureString -AsPlainText # 'Exam ...
+                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertFrom-SecureString], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromSecureStringCommand
```

When I run those commands without *-AsPlainText* it returns:

```
01000000d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb0100000063db09d0a5a25b4d92484ee7d5911cf90000000002000000000003660000c00000001000000098fcbc0d5e009078dd7a1dfe9f24d3380000000004800000a00000001000000027a7f841c320bc17b5e4febbcd3e49551000000005a133e9f864340d9d7b2473939156ef14000000f889bf5c0fc4799a5aaf435ebb15cd0920f24575
```

Is this a Microsoft issue or is this not supported in PowerShell 5.1

**PowerShell Version**

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      18362  628
```

Comment: Question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352141/convert-a-secure-string-to-plain-text

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's [not supported in PowerShell 5.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertfrom-securestring?view=powershell-5.1). `ConvertFrom-SecureString` doesn't support the
`-AsPlainText` parameter until PowerShell Core 7+.

---

If you want to get the plain text string from a plain text `SecureString` in PowerShell prior to 7, use the following methods:

```
$bstr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secureString)
$plaintext = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($bstr)
```

`$plaintext` will be your plaintext string converted from the `SecureString` you passed in.