# Add Windows Credentials using PowerShell & cmdkey

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line-tool

I am trying to use credentials from some UI prompted to add Windows credentials using *[cmdkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Management_features_new_to_Windows_Vista#Command-line_tools)*:

```
$sessionCredential = $host.ui.PromptForCredential("Need credentials", "Please enter your user name and password.", "", "Server Crdentials")
$ps = ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $sessionCredential.password
cmdkey.exe /add:server1 /user:$($sessionCredential.UserName) /pass:$($ps)
```

The credentials are added correctly, but the password is not.

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: Are you sure the password is not correct? The Credentials manager GUI never shows the correct number of digits there, so it just might _look_ as though this is wrong..

Comment: yes, i manually edit the passwords on the credentials UI to check and the passwords is wrong

Comment: please add your code for assigning $host

Comment: The fourth parameter to [PromptForCredential()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface.promptforcredential) (*targetName* - *"Name of the target for which the credential is being collected."*)  *seems* to be ***[misspelt](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/credential#Noun):*** *"`Server Crdentials`"*. It *seems* to be significant, not just an informational message. Is it significant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the problem is **ConvertFrom-SecureString** is returning an **encrypted standard string**, [ConvertFrom-SecureString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertfrom-securestring?view=powershell-5.1).

And the option to get *plain text* is not available on PowerShell 5.1.

I found the correct convert [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352141/convert-a-secure-string-to-plain-text).

I understand it is not secured. It is used inside secured clients.

See fixed code below:

```
$sessionCredential = $host.ui.PromptForCredential("Need credentials", "Please enter your user name and password.", "", "Server Crdentials")
$mpass = [System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new("",$sessionCredential.password).Password
cmdkey.exe /add:server1 /user:$($sessionCredential.UserName) /pass:$($mpass)
```

Comment: It is still *"Server Crdentials"*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen That 4th arg is the Domain Name.  In my case I wanted to use this for web not Windows, so I called it "FAKEDOMAIN" and then instead of the cmdkey line I did `$user=$sessionCredential.UserName.Replace("FAKEDOMAIN\","")`

Answer (score 2):

Use the [CredentialManager](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/CredentialManager/2.0) PowerShell module. It saves the password in the same place as `cmdkey`, but it can take [PSCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscredential) objects directly without needing to convert to text.

```
Import-Module CredentialManager

# Get the credential from the user with a windows credentials prompt:
$SessionCredential = Get-Credential -Message 'Please enter your server credentials'

# Save the credential object directly without unwrapping it:
New-StoredCredential -Credentials $SessionCredential -Target ServerCredentials -Persist Enterprise `
  -Comment "Server Credentials for $($SessionCredential.UserName)" > $null

# Open the credential later
$SavedCred = Get-StoredCredential -Target ServerCredentials

# Delete if needed
Remove-StoredCredential -Target ServerCredentials
```

`cmdkey /pass:$($ps)` is prone to errors due to PowerShell garbling password characters.

Comment: i cannot add module to the client machine where this script is running , sorry